# Signed column sum for Young tableau $t$

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, young-tableaux

I am currently working on the book *The Symmetric Group* by Bruce Sagan.

The following passage comes before introducing Specht Modules:

> Suppose that the tableau $t$ has rows $R_1, R_2, ..., R_l$ and columns
>   $C_1, C_2, ..., C_k$. Then $$R_t = S_{R_1} \times S_{R_2} \times ... \times S_{R_l}$$ and $$C_t = S_{C_1} \times S_{C_2} \times ... \times S_{C_k}$$ are the *row-stabiliser* and the *column-stabiliser* of $t$, respectively.
>
> ---
>
> We define $\kappa_t = \sum \limits_{\pi \in C_t} \text{sgn}(\pi) \pi$.
>
> Note that $\kappa_t$ factors as $$\kappa_t =\kappa_{C_1}\kappa_{C_2}...\kappa_{C_k}.$$

Unfortunately I cannot see a way how to prove that this is true. I think that the right hand side represents a [product of group subsets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_subgroups).

So, using the definitions, I am wondering, why $$\sum \limits_{\pi \in C_t} \text{sgn}(\pi) \pi = \sum \limits_{\pi \in C_1} \text{sgn}(\pi) \pi\sum \limits_{\pi \in C_2} \text{sgn}(\pi) \pi~...\sum \limits_{\pi \in C_k} \text{sgn}(\pi) \pi.$$

Do you know how to prove this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It's not a product of group subsets, but a product in the group algebra (as he states explicitly when he defines $H^{\pm}$ between the two text fragments that you quoted).

Comment: Oh, sorry that I did not see this! Thank you for the reply! How could I prove this when the $\kappa_i$s are group algebras? I tried to find a definition of the product of algebras in the internet, but I could not find anything. Thanks again very much!

Comment: No need to look on the internet when you have the book. ;-) The group algebra is defined in Section 1.3. (And it's not a "product of algebras", it's a product of *elements* in the group algebra. An algebra is just a vector space where you can also multiply the vectors to get a new vector.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction! But I still cannot see how to go in proving this ...

Comment: Did you try writing out the product for a concrete example, like the tableau (2.1) for instance? If you do that, I think you will find the statement quite obvious.

Comment: I have written it out, giving me $\kappa_t = (e,e,e) - ((4,3),e,e) - (e,(1,5),e) + ((4,3),(1,5),e)$ and $\kappa_{C_1}\kappa_{C_2}\kappa_{C_3} = e - (3,4) - (1,5) + (1,5)(3,4)$. In the first case we have elements involving a direct product, whereas in the second case we don't have such elements. It is clear to me, which element has to correspond to which, but is it right, when we say that both are equivalent? Thank you very much again!

Comment: Yes, that's right! By abuse of notation, he is considering the direct products as subgroups of $S_n$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914545/a-basis-for-specht-modules help!